# How to fix broken file.module function 'file_ajax_progress' without hacking the core and patching after every update?

Tags: 7, ajax, caching, files

When site has enabled page cache and anonymous user tries to upload a file, he cannot see upload status progress. He see only message "*Starting upload...*". [Bug](https://www.drupal.org/node/1627162) was reported in June 2012, has a working [patch](https://www.drupal.org/files/file_progress_page_cache.patch) and I have a question:

How to fix broken **file.module** function [**`file_ajax_progress`**](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!file!file.module/function/file_ajax_progress/7) without hacking the core and patching after every update? Should I do some function override by custom module?

This is all working code together:

```
/**
 * Menu callback for upload progress.
 *
 * @param $key
 *   The unique key for this upload process.
 */
function file_ajax_progress($key) {
  $progress = array(
    'message' => t('Starting upload...'),
    'percentage' => -1,
  );

  $implementation = file_progress_implementation();
  if ($implementation == 'uploadprogress') {
    $status = uploadprogress_get_info($key);
    if (isset($status['bytes_uploaded']) && !empty($status['bytes_total'])) {
      $progress['message'] = t('Uploading... (@current of @total)', array('@current' => format_size($status['bytes_uploaded']), '@total' => format_size($status['bytes_total'])));
      $progress['percentage'] = round(100 * $status['bytes_uploaded'] / $status['bytes_total']);
    }
  }
  elseif ($implementation == 'apc') {
    $status = apc_fetch('upload_' . $key);
    if (isset($status['current']) && !empty($status['total'])) {
      $progress['message'] = t('Uploading... (@current of @total)', array('@current' => format_size($status['current']), '@total' => format_size($status['total'])));
      $progress['percentage'] = round(100 * $status['current'] / $status['total']);
    }
  }
  // Mark this page as being uncacheable.
  drupal_page_is_cacheable(FALSE);
  drupal_json_output($progress);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is simple: make a module. So I created one. Module has name [Upload progress fix](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/jasom/2606172).

Answer (score 1):

Patching core is not the same as hacking core.  Many of us have patched versions of Drupal in the wild (eg, using [Secure Pages](https://www.drupal.org/project/securepages)).

You need to work out how you want to manage this between upgrades.

On sites where I don't track Drupal's repo, I keep a directory of patches next to the DOCROOT.  Before I upgrade, I check on whether the patch is needed or not.  I then `drush pm-update drupal` and apply patches.

On sites that I have [built with git](https://www.drupal.org/node/803746), I can typically build the site in its own branch, apply patches, and then upgrade core versions by merging the latest tag and doing the database updates.

Comment: 1th. Thank you. 2nd. You basically wrote: _refix it after every update_. I think, it's not the best possible option. I have updated my question.